# 1980s anime movie - alien moonbase

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I saw this anime movie in the 1980s and I am pretty sure it was new then (but I could be wrong). Humans have colonized the Moon and discovered an abandoned alien base in the process. I never saw the whole story, so I don't know if the aliens ever returned - what I did see was human political intrigue over who controls the base.

Comment: Do you have more info? Perhaps a mecha appeared over there?

Comment: I don't remember any more. But I never saw the end, so maybe a mecha suck in somewhere.

Comment: this sounds like some part of a gundamish, this series is so political at times.

Comment: Dallos was my first and only thought when reading the question title/description.  I don’t think too much clarification is called for here.  On the other hand perhaps I have limited exposure to “alien moon base”-themed media.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might this be *[Dallos](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/dallos)*?

[image]

Released in 1983, it features a human colony on the Moon who discover a mysterious structure, resembling a giant face staring up at the sky.

It was a four-episode series, but they were also edited together and released on video as a movie.

Synopsis:

> Decades ago, the moon was colonized and turned into a mining colony whose profits benefited Earth and its people. A generation has passed and the workers are now treated as slaves -- forced to work in the mines under the rule of earth-born men, with many of the young people having never been to the land of their heritage. The time has come, however, for a rebellion to take place: to command Earth to hear their pleas; and afterwards, the moon and Dallos, the moon's god-like structure who silently sleeps and protects its inhabitants, will never be the same...

Comment: [Here's a nice article](https://cartoonresearch.com/index.php/forgotten-anime-43-dallos-1983/) on it, in case it's of interest.